# Unload all records of a specific type from the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to do the following:

```
App.Availablephone.all().forEach(function(phone, index) {
    phone.unloadRecord();
});
```

Unfortunately, since `.all()` is a live array, this is not working (the array is being modified during the loop, and gets completely mixed up).

How can I unload all records of a specific type from the store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the toArray method to get a static array of existing records.

```
var array = App.Availablephone.all().toArray();

// Records to unload:
array.forEach(function(item) { 
  console.log('unloading record: ', item.toString()); 
  item.unloadRecord();
})
```

Comment: This would still not remove the records from the store, right? I mean, the live array `.all()` would stay unaffected?

Comment: Actually it should remove the records from the store. The live array returned by `.all()` will change as each item is unloaded.

Comment: Where i can use it? route: beforeModel?

Answer (score 12):

While the selected answer works, ember-data provides an unloadAll method on the store that accomplishes this exact thing.

```
store.unloadAll('availablephone');
```

This works with the 1.0.0 beta releases, link to the source is below
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/e4e3e3ec6b0289438a6b15c36407369fedf3eb40/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L717

Comment: FYI, there is currently a bug with the unloadAll implementation. There is a PR https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1482 to fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but I still wanted to have SO reflect that there is a standard method to accomplish this in ember-data.

Comment: @DeewendraShrestha the code is still there in the master branch... https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L789

Comment: Yeah but I had this store.unloadAll put in beforeModel hook because we wanted to kill all the records before we hit a particular route. And it was aborting the transition, when debugging through the beforeModel hook, the debugger owuld just the script execution when it reached unloadAll but without any error though. However when I tried the solution provided by Mike, it was working without any glitch.